# Microsoft JScript compilation error 800A0404 at tailwind.js file

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tailwind-css

I'm using fuse material UI theme and I am trying to run the project by `npm start` the JavaScript file tailwind.js shows the error as shown in the figure attached and I am getting 800A0404 Microsoft Jscript compilation error.

[image]

Tailwind.js File

```
  module.exports = {
    prefix: "",
    important: false,
    separator: ":",
    theme: {
      extend: {
        screens: {
          sm: "600px",
          md: "960px",
          lg: "1280px",
          xl: "1920px",
          print: { raw: "print" },
        },
        colors: {
          transparent: "transparent",
          black: "#22292F",
          white: "#FFF",
          grey: {
            50: "#FAFAFA",
            100: "#F5F5F5",
            200: "#EEEEEE",
            300: "#E0E0E0",
            400: "#BDBDBD",
            500: "#9E9E9E",
            default: "#9E9E9E",
            600: "#757575",
            700: "#616161",
            800: "#424242",
            900: "#212121",
            A100: "#D5D5D5",
            A200: "#AAAAAA",
            A400: "#303030",
            A700: "#616161",
          },
          gray: {
            50: "#FAFAFA",
            100: "#F5F5F5",
            200: "#EEEEEE",
            300: "#E0E0E0",
            400: "#BDBDBD",
            500: "#9E9E9E",
            default: "#9E9E9E",
            600: "#757575",
            700: "#616161",
            800: "#424242",
            900: "#212121",
            A100: "#D5D5D5",
            A200: "#AAAAAA",
            A400: "#303030",
            A700: "#616161",
          },
          red: {
            50: "#FFEBEE",
            100: "#FFCDD2",
            200: "#EF9A9A",
            300: "#E57373",
            400: "#EF5350",
            500: "#F44336",
            default: "#F44336",
            600: "#E53935",
            700: "#D32F2F",
            800: "#C62828",
            900: "#B71C1C",
            A100: "#FF8A80",
            A200: "#FF5252",
            A400: "#FF1744",
            A700: "#D50000",
          },
          orange: {
            50: "#FFF3E0",
            100: "#FFE0B2",
            200: "#FFCC80",
            300: "#FFB74D",
            400: "#FFA726",
            500: "#FF9800",
            default: "#FF9800",
            600: "#FB8C00",
            700: "#F57C00",
            800: "#EF6C00",
            900: "#E65100",
            A100: "#FFD180",
            A200: "#FFAB40",
            A400: "#FF9100",
            A700: "#FF6D00",
          },
          "deep-orange": {
            50: "#FBE9E7",
            100: "#FFCCBC",
            200: "#FFAB91",
            300: "#FF8A65",
            400: "#FF7043",
            500: "#FF5722",
            default: "#FF5722",
            600: "#F4511E",
            700: "#E64A19",
            800: "#D84315",
            900: "#BF360C",
            A100: "#FF9E80",
            A200: "#FF6E40",
            A400: "#FF3D00",
            A700: "#DD2C00",
          },
          yellow: {
            50: "#FFFDE7",
            100: "#FFF9C4",
            200: "#FFF59D",
            300: "#FFF176",
            400: "#FFEE58",
            500: "#FFEB3B",
            default: "#FFEB3B",
            600: "#FDD835",
            700: "#FBC02D",
            800: "#F9A825",
            900: "#F57F17",
            A100: "#FFFF8D",
            A200: "#FFFF00",
            A400: "#FFEA00",
            A700: "#FFD600",
          },
        },
    },
    corePlugins: {},
  plugins: [],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to change `tailwind.js` to something else like `tailwind.config.js`. Don't forget to update the name of this file in `postcss.config.js` too.