# npm start has tailwind.js popup Error 800A0404 jScript compilation error then blank browser screen

Tags: javascript, compilation, tailwind-in-js

When I do npm start in the portal dir it has the error message:

```
Script: c:\users\me\IdeaProjects\portal\cp-frontend\tailwind.js 
Line 32, char 7
Error: expected identifier, string or number 
Code: 800A0404. 
Source: Microsoft JScript compilation error.
```

The info on the screen before the error message and after npm start is:

```
>npm start

> start
> concurrently -k -n 'frontend,backend' "npm run start-frontend" "npm run start-backend"

[frontend]
[frontend] > start-frontend
[frontend] > cd cp-frontend && npm run start
[frontend]
[backend]
[backend] > start-backend
[backend] > cd cp-backend && npm run start
[backend]
[frontend]
[frontend] > customer-portal-frontend@0.1.0 start
[frontend] > npm run tailwind:css && react-scripts start
[frontend]
[backend]
[backend] > customer-portal-poc@1.0.0 start
[backend] > nodemon -r dotenv/config index.js
[backend]
[backend] [nodemon] 2.0.2
[backend] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[backend] [nodemon] watching dir(s): *.*
[backend] [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[backend] [nodemon] starting `node -r dotenv/config index.js`
[backend] Server listening on port: 3002
[frontend]
[frontend] > customer-portal-frontend@0.1.0 tailwind:css
[frontend] > tailwind build src/tailwind.src.css -c tailwind.js -o src/tailwind.css
[frontend]
[frontend] npm run start-frontend exited with code 1
--> Sending SIGTERM to other processes..
[backend] npm run start-backend exited with code 1
```

My tailwind.js file looks like this (line 32 shown in added comment):

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: '#63ACE5',
        background: '#E6EFF6',
        'blue-light': '#63ACE5',
        'blue': '#4C86B5',
        'blue-dark': '#2A4E68',
        accent: '#FCAB4D'
      },
      spacing: {
        px: '1px',
        '0': '0',
        '1': '0.25rem',
        '2': '0.5rem',
        '3': '0.75rem',
        '4': '1rem',
        '5': '1.25rem',
        '6': '1.5rem',
        '8': '2rem',
        '10': '2.5rem',
        '12': '3rem',
        '16': '4rem',
        '20': '5rem',
        '24': '6rem',
        '32': '8rem',
        '40': '10rem',
        '48': '12rem',
        '56': '14rem',
        '64': '16rem',
      },  //this is line 32
      screens: {
        'sm': '640px',
        // => @media (min-width: 640px) { ... }
  
        'md': '768px',
        // => @media (min-width: 768px) { ... }
  
        'lg': '1024px',
        // => @media (min-width: 1024px) { ... }
  
        'xl': '1280px',
        // => @media (min-width: 1280px) { ... }
      }
    },
  },
  variants: {
    tableLayout: ['responsive', 'hover', 'focus'],
    borderWidth: ['responsive', 'first', 'last', 'hover', 'focus'],
    padding: ['responsive', 'first', 'last'],
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

I'm looking at these threads, [tailwind file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66437196/microsoft-jscript-compilation-error-800a0404-at-tailwind-js-file) or [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60693700/microsoft-jscript-compilation-error-800a0404), but since this web page is a running web page in prod, I doubt I'd need to edit my tailwinds file or rename a file.

I have built the project in IntelliJ idea.

Update1: I tried [npm install -g yarn](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/18701) but still get the same error message.

Update:
I tried renaming tailwind.js to tailwind.config.js in cp-frontend and also it's reference in package.json.  Npm start had error:

```
Failed to compile layout.js. Module not found can’t resolve react.router
```

I did the following:

in root dir and cp-frontend dir:

```
npm install react-router-dom
npm install react-router-config
```

I didn't get popup error after that, but had errors:

```
[frontend]   Line 21:6:   React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'register'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
[frontend]
[frontend] ./src/components/user/findProperty/FindProperty.js
[frontend]   Line 47:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'register'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
[frontend]
[frontend] ./src/components/user/dashboard/PastPayments.js
[frontend]   Line 4:8:  'ChevronIcon' is defined but never used   no-unused-vars
[frontend]   Line 5:8:  'DownloadIcon' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
[frontend]
[frontend] ./src/components/common/alerts/Alerts.js
[frontend]   Line 54:6:  React Hook useEffect has an unnecessary dependency: 'fetchAlertData'. Either exclude it or remove the dependency array. Outer scope values like 'fetchAlertData' aren't valid dependencies because mutating them doesn't re-render the component  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
[frontend]
[frontend] ./src/components/user/pastBills/PastBills.js
[frontend]   Line 66:6:   React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'history', 'params', 'serviceAccounts', and 'showFileInUrl'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
[frontend]   Line 93:11:  <iframe> elements must have a unique title property                                                                                                             jsx-a11y/iframe-has-title
[frontend]
[frontend] ./src/components/user/dashboard/CustomerSvcTable.js
[frontend]   Line 7:22:  'formatCurrencyNum' is defined but never used                                                                   no-unused-vars
[frontend]   Line 34:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'getSvcOrder'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
[frontend]
[frontend] ./src/components/user/layout/Layout.js
[frontend]   Line 80:6:   React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'fetchInitialData'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
[frontend]   Line 86:20:  'Tawk_API' was used before it was defined                                                                            no-use-before-define
[frontend]   Line 91:9:   'Tawk_LoadStart' is assigned a value but never used                                                                  no-unused-vars
[frontend]
[frontend] ./src/components/common/navbar/Navbar.js
[frontend]   Line 91:15:  No duplicate props allowed  react/jsx-no-duplicate-props
[frontend]
[frontend] ./src/components/common/card/Card.js
[frontend]   Line 94:21:  Using target="_blank" without rel="noopener noreferrer" is a security risk: see https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener  react/jsx-no-target-blank
[frontend]
[frontend] Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
[frontend] To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.
```

My question now is, do I need to add the missing dependencies to the package.json for the frontend? I'm sure they will go away if I do npm install , but I'm unclear on the permanent fix. Do the dependency list items have an order?  The browser popped up with a blank screen but the debugging tool doesn't show an error that I can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tailwind-js-popup-error-800a0404- went away after
renaming tailwind.js to tailwind.config.js in cp-frontend and also it's reference in package.json. Npm start had error:

Failed to compile layout.js. Module not found can’t resolve react.router
I did the following:

in root dir and cp-frontend dir:

npm install react-router-dom
npm install react-router-config

The blank screen and error messages went away after I moved the link to Edge instead of IE.